# Vim - convert 4 spaces to bullet

Tags: vim

I have a document like such:

```
asdf
    asdf 
    asdf
        asdf
asdf
    asdf 
        asdf
    asdf
```

I want to convert this into the following or something more readable with -, ==, *, etc... depending on 4*n spaces (tab == 4 spaces in my vim)

```
- asdf
    - asdf 
    - asdf
        - asdf
- asdf
    - asdf 
        - asdf
    - asdf
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
:%s/[^ ]/- &/
```

Replace the first non space character with `-` and the character.

Comment: I can accept this answer in 12 minutes. You are too fast.